# How do I send the result of my MySQL Query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

Im developing a Discord Bot with discordjs and mysql and I wanted to ask how I can send the Result of my query in the embed to the user that requests it. My Code looks like this:
If you have any solutions or ideas how to do it please share it with me.
(I removed a little bit of code on the top)

````
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "/",
    user: "/",
    password: "/",
    database: "/"
});


client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    const { commandName } = interaction;
    if (commandName === 'submit') {
        conn.query(`INSERT INTO discordtest(userID, tag) VALUES ('${interaction.user.id}' , '${interaction.user.tag}')`)
        await interaction.reply(':white_check_mark: Daten erfolgreich hinterlegt!');
        interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    }
        
    else if(commandName === 'info'){
    

conn.query(`SELECT licenses FROM discordtest WHERE userID=${interaction.user.id}`, (err, msg) =>{ 
            var message = msg.content;
                     if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                  }else
                console.log(msg)
            });

    const infoEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('Webseite')
    .setURL('https://zockercraft.de/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'User Info', iconURL: 'https://zockercraft.de/discordbild/bild.jpg'})
    .setDescription(`Hier sind die Daten zu ${interaction.user.tag}:`)
    .setThumbnail(interaction.user.avatarURL())
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Test', value: 'test' , inline: true },
        { name: 'Test', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Designed by: DerBZocker2#9955'
});
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [infoEmbed] }); 
 
 
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

```js
conn.query(`SELECT licenses FROM discordtest WHERE userID='${interaction.user.id}'`, (err, msg) => { 
    var message = msg.content; //What is this for?
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription(`${msg.userID}`) //msg will give you the details 
        //of your informations. connecting with '.' then add 'userID'
        .setColor(0x0099FF)
        .setTitle('Webseite')

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [infoEmbed] }); 
    }
});
```

I only have a small knowledge of interactions commands. But I think you only need to get the data. So it should do the trick